# rescaling a matplotlib.colorbar and matplotlib.contour after creation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a contourplot, generated using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
Y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
ZZ = XX**2 + YY**2
levels = np.linspace(0, 200, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cf = ax.contourf(X, Y, ZZ, levels=levels)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cf)
```

This generates this figure:

[image]

Now imagine, that for some reason, the figure is handed to the user through some functions call, and the user only gets the `ax`, `fig`, and `cbar` objects.

UPDATE: The reason I want to do this, is because I have to make a gargantuan amount of contourplots in an automated way. I have automated the creation of the contourplot in the backend (vaguely described as "the function call" here above). But for some plots, some slight modification is required to generated exquisite plots. So instead of manipulating the backed or having to add numerous amounts of options for every situation, it would be nice if the couple of figures I need to adjust out of the +400 figures are adjustable through the `ax`, `fig`, and `cbar` objects.

Now only manipulating those objects, I want to zoom in, and rescale both the colorbar as well as the levels.

Zooming in:

```
ax.set_xlim(2.5, 7.5)
ax.set_ylim(2.5, 7.5)
```

[image]

Changing the limit on the colorbar and the ticks:

```
new_clim = (0, 100)
# find location of the new upper limit on the color bar
loc_on_cbar = cbar.norm(new_clim[1])
# redefine limits of the colorbar
cf.colorbar.set_clim(*new_clim)
cf.colorbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(*new_clim, 10))
# redefine the limits of the levels of the contour
cf.set_clim(*new_clim)
# updating the contourplot
cf.changed()
```

[image]

Changing the scale of the colorbar itself:

```
cbar.ax.set_ylim(0, loc_on_cbar)
cbar.ax.autoscale_view()
```

[image]

Now there are some issues here:

1. I cannot seem the find how to rescale the colorbar's axis without having that annoying empty rectangle on top.
2. I cannot find howto adjust the number of levels in the contourplot & colorbar after creating the instance.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think that you can change the number of levels of `cf` after creation. The `contourf` function returns a [QuadContourSet](https://matplotlib.org/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet), which, I think, doesn't have any information on the function from which the contours are derived.

Comment: If you know which plots should be altered before creating them, simply changing the creation method to zooming in on the right location in the first place would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: For the colorbar, have you tried only calling `cf.set_clim()` and leaving out the other calls (i.e. `cf.colorbar.set_clim()` and so forth) and then calling `fig.canvas.draw()` after that?

Comment: @ThomasKühn: Yes, this yields the same result as in figure 3. [Thanks for the tip on the QuadContourSet, I'll check it out.]